# Deleting a line from a text file more than once

Tags: java

I'm trying to delete a line from a text file, the code below works, although I can't seem to delete more than once. After I've inputted the ID in the text field and clicked delete, it works just fine but I can't do it again.

```
String filepath = "..\\rent-a-car\\assets\\car.txt";
    private void btnDelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String tempFile = "..\\rent-a-car\\assets\\temp.txt";
        String removeTerm = jTextField1.getText();
        File oldFile = new File(filepath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);
        String id = ""; String make = ""; String model = ""; String year = ""; String color = ""; String rent = "";
        Scanner sc;
        
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            sc = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            sc.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
            
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                id    = sc.next();
                make  = sc.next();
                model = sc.next();
                year  = sc.next();
                color = sc.next();
                rent  = sc.next();
                
                if(!id.equals(removeTerm)){
                    pw.println(id + "," + make + "," + model + "," + year + "," + color + "," + rent + "\n");
                }
            }
           
            sc.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(filepath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);
        
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        } 
        
    }
```

Comment: How does the file content look after first pass?
What kind of error do you get?
Also, you are catching an exception silently and all your resources might be leaked. You should use try-with-resources.

Comment: Do you expect more than one line to be deleted, or are you checking the file, then clicking the button again?

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and post a sample of the input file `car.txt` and what you expect the file to contain after method `btnDelActionPerformed()` has completed, as well as what you are actually getting now when you run your code.